# XOR higher 32 bits with lower 32 bits in a 64 bit number

Tags: c++, algorithm

In a 64 bit number How to XOR Higher order 32 bits with lower order 32 bits.
Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(v & 0xffffffff) ^ ((v >> 32) & 0xffffffff)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking the second bit mask isn’t necessary.

Comment: Even if the variable is signed?

Comment: @Ignacio Bit arithmetic on signed integers … *shudder*. No, you’re right.

Comment: I thought that integer literals in C/C++ must have specifier such as `L` on the end or them will be truncated. Am I right?

Comment: None of those literals are larger than 32 bits.

Comment: @George No.  The type of a literal depends on its suffix, whether it is decimal or not, and its value: for each combination of suffix and base, there is a list of types, and the first type big enough to represent its value will be used.  In the case of hex and no suffix, the list is `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long`.  (Note that `0xFFFFFFFF` will be signed on some machines, and unsigned on others.  Fun and games.)

Comment: @Konrad If you only want one mask take `(v ^ (v >> 32)) & 0xffffffff`

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks, here's another solution. The one given already is probably the way to go.

```
uint32_t* number32;
uint64_t number64 = 0xffff1111ffffffff;
uint32_t xorValue;

number32 = (uint32_t*)&number64;
xorValue = number32[0]^number32[1];
```

Comment: Looks like type punning, your compiler won't like that if you're making aliasing assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint32_t hi_low_xor(uint64_t x) {
  return static_cast<uint32_t>(x) ^ static_cast<uint32_t>(x >> 32);
}
```

Comment: Wrong. The result can be over 32 bit that is obvious incorrect.

Comment: @Artem. It is not true. XOR for the pair of 32-bit numbers is always 32-bit number.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store the result in lower 32 bits:

```
(v & 0xffffffff) ^ ((v >> 32))
```

if you want to store the result in higher 32 bits:

```
((v & 0xffffffff) ^ ((v >> 32))) << 32
```